# Binding custom object list data to a Data Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

Im trying to Bind a Custom data list to a `Datagrid` in WPF

This is the custom object:

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Role{ get; set; }
}
```

From the data base I fetch this data as a list

```
public List<User> allUsers;
```

I send this list to the view Model class ->

```
public ListWindowViewModel(object dataSource)
{
     this.datasource = dataSource;
}

public DataView GridData
{       
    get
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet("ListData");    
        ds = dataSource as DataSet;    
        return ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
    }
 }
```

Inside my ListView xaml file I used binding ->

```
<DataGrid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Margin="3" x:Name="mainGrid"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=GridData, Mode=OneWay}">
        </DataGrid>
```

Its not working becase the `ds = dataSource as DataSet;` is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can directly Create the collection like.

```
 private ObservableCollection<User> _allUsers=new ObservableCollection<User>();

    public ObservableCollection<User> allUsers
    {
        get { return _allUsers; }
        set { _allUsers = value; }
    }
```

and your datagrid Binding look like

```
<DataGrid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Margin="3" x:Name="mainGrid"
              ItemsSource="{Binding=allUsers, Mode=OneWay}">
    </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried to use directly a binding? Like:

(nameDatagrid).ItemSource = null;

(nameDatagrid).ItemSource = allUsers;